# Is an injective morphism from a Lie group to itself surjective?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-homomorphism

I have a question about Lie groups. Let $G$ be a finite dimensional (real or complex) Lie group and $f:G \rightarrow G$ an homomorphism of Lie groups. **Edit :** in the view of some counter-examples let's also suppose $G$ connected.

**Q1 :** Suppose that $f$ is injective, is it then surjective ?

Here are my attempts so far to adress this question. It is known that an injective Lie homomorphism is an immersion so the differential $df_g$ of $f$ in any point $g\in G$ is injective. For reasons of dimension, $df_g$ is then bijective. Thus, by the inversion theorem, $f$ is a diffeormorphism from $G$ to $f(G)\leq G$.

Moreover, it is also well known that $f(G) \simeq G/Ker(f) \simeq G/\lbrace e \rbrace \simeq G$. So we have a subgroup $f(G)$ of $G$ isomorphic to $G$. Then, we can reduce the question to :

**Q2 :** Let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of $G$. If $H \simeq G$, do we have $H=G$ ?

Now, maybe we can progress with some topological argument. Typically, I think of the fundamental group, that is useful to link the classification of Lie groups to the classification of Lie algebras. As $H$ is diffeomorphic to $G$, we have $\pi(H)=\pi(G)$. Hence a third question :

**Q3 :** Let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of $G$. If $Lie(H)=Lie(G)$ and $\pi(H)=\pi(G)$, do we have $H=G$ ?

After that, I have to admit that I don't have ideas about where to look. So if someone as an answer, a hint or a reference, that would be awesome.

In addition, I have a few "bonus" questions around this subject :

**B1 :** If the answer to the questions above is no, what is a counterexample ? Is there a simple hypothesis we can add so that it becomes true ?

**B2 :** What are the possible generalisations to all this discussion ? For example with infinite dimensional Lie groups ? With topological groups ?

**B3 :** In the other way around, if $f\in Hom(G,G)$ is surjective, is it injective ?

Thanks a lot to all who have read till the end and to the ones who will answer.

Comment: $G = \mathbb{Z}$ viewed as a (non-compact, disconnected) $0$-dimensional Lie group provides counter-examples to all 3 of your questions (with $f(x) = 2x$ and $H=2G$).

Comment: Indeed it does, thanks for answering. And for $G$ connected ? Or $G$ compact ? Do you know ?

Comment: For $G$ compact, $SO(3) \subset O(3)$ is a counterexample to Q3.

Comment: Perhaps you should add to the question the assumption that $G$ is connected?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: You should be able to answer Q1 for yourself now, since the image of $f$ and its complement are both open by your observation that $f$ must be a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Hmm, I think I agree but I just have a little doubt. Are we sure that the fact that $f$ is a diffeomorphism from $G$ to $f(G)$ means that $f(G)$ is open in $G$ ?

Comment: Yes, every local homeomorphism of topological spaces is an open map. Since diffeomorphisms are local diffeomorphisms are local homeomorphisms and $G$ is open in itself, it follows that $f(G)$ is open in $G$.

Comment: Yes thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer, and to summarize some discussion in both the question and the comments:

If $G$ is connected and $f : G \to G$ is injective, then it is an immersion, hence a local diffeomorphism, hence open. But the only open subgroup of a connected topological group $G$ is $G$ itself, since any open neighborhood of the identity in $G$ generates $G$. Hence $f$ is surjective.

So with connectivity, the answers to **Q1, Q2, Q3** are all **yes**, and in Q3 the extra hypothesis on fundamental groups is unnecessary.

The answer to a slightly different version of **Q3** is **no**: you might ask whether two connected Lie groups are isomorphic if their Lie algebras and fundamental groups are isomorphic. As a counterexample, $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$, and hence it admits a unique connected double cover whose fundamental group is also $\mathbb{Z}$ (and which also has Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$), the [metaplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group) $Mp_2(\mathbb{R})$. These two Lie groups are not isomorphic: the metaplectic group has no faithful finite-dimensional representations.

It's a bit trickier to find a compact counterexample, but it can still be done: $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ double covers three Lie groups, namely $SU(2) \times SO(3), SO(3) \times SU(2)$, and $SO(4)$. All of these have the same Lie algebra (namely $\mathfrak{su}(2) \times \mathfrak{su}(2)$) and fundamental group (namely $\mathbb{Z}_2$) but $SO(4)$ is not isomorphic to $SU(2) \times SO(3)$: their representation theory is different.

The answer to another slightly different version of **Q3** is **yes**: you might ask whether a map $f : G \to H$ of connected Lie groups is an isomorphism if it induces an isomorphism on Lie algebras and on $\pi_1$. This is true and follows from covering space theory, since the first hypothesis implies that $f$ induces an isomorphism on universal covers.